# Erro ao redirecionar para https UOL Host

Tags: htaccess, apache

Tenho um site hospedado na **UOL HOST**.

Estou configurando um `.htaccess` na esperança de que 2 coisas ocorram:

A) Todo acesso por `http` seja convertido para `httpS`

B) TODO e qualquer acesso (Links **existentes** e **NÃO existentes**), sejam redirecionados para a **index.php**

Estou fazendo dessa forma:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

Bom, o **redirecionamento** para a **index** está **perfeito**!

Mas quando tento de **http** para **https**, embora esteja habilitado o **https** no serviro e o arquivo possa ser **acessado** **diretamente** caso essa **diretiva** **NÃO** esteja no `.htaccess` dá informação de que

```
Esta página não está funcionando
```

Mas a página só tem o texto HOME nela e nada mais

Answer (score 2):

Para quem interessar possa. Pois para mim essa solução funcionou em partes.

```
# Redirecionar para HTTPS WC
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Páginas e diretórios com erros de acesso ou código
ErrorDocument 401 /401.php
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
ErrorDocument 500 /500.php


# Reenvia todas páginas e diretórios ENCONTRADOS para o index
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [NC]
```

Mas ainda ficaram duas dúvidas:

A) Necessário fazer o `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` no início? Porquê?

B) Porque, embora caso eu fala `httpS` para um arquivo, o `httpS` abre corretamente, mas o redirecionamento não ocorre caso acesse o mesmo link com `http` ao invés de `httpS`,

Obs.: Isso só acontece em `LOCALHOST`. Na internet funciona normalmente!

Uma coisa que percebi é que se eu alterar no httpd.conf a diretiva

```
AllowOverride None
```

para

```
AllowOverride All
```

Ainda que eu abra um **arquivo vazio**, ele já abrirá com `erro 500`

Ou seja, parece que o `Apache` não está aceitando a permissão de `.htaccess`